# Реализовываем роли доступа на PHP сайте

Tags: права, php

Добрый вечер, господа. Сейчас разрабатываю интернет-магазин на самописной CMS. И возникла необходимость реализовать роли доступа для администратора, пользователя, гостя и модератора. Но как их реализовать понятия не имею, а поисковые системы пока не дали ответ на этот вопрос. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, ссылками, что нужно почитать или поделитесь опытом... Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Честно, если вы задаёте такие вопросы, то не стоит писать интернет-магазин.

Comment: простой способ - добавьте поле role в таблицу пользователей, и распределите ранги, допустим role = 1 - обычный пользователь, role = 2 - зарегистрированный пользователь, role = 3 - администратор. А где вам нужно просто дёргайте значение role и проверяйте условиями

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Самый тривиальный способ: нужно каждому юзеру назначить уровень доступа, а при совершении какого-то действия – проверять, достаточно ли у него прав. Например, вот таблица пользователей:

```
id | login      | pwd | rank
 1 | admin      | *** | 99
 2 | user       | *** | 1
 3 | user2      | *** | 1
 4 | manager    | *** | 50
 5 | superadmin | *** | 100
```

Допустим, при аутентификации данные о пользователе записываются в сессию так:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = array(
    'id' => 4,
    'login' => 'manager',
    'rank' => 50,
    );
```

Тогда при совершении какого-то действия нужно просто проверять, достаточно ли у текущего пользователя прав:

```
...
if ($_GET['action'] == 'save-user-profile')
    {
    if ($_SESSION['user']['rank'] >= 50)
        {
        $db->users->replacerow($_POST['profile']);
        echo 'Профиль успешно сохранен';
        }
    else
        {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
        die('Недостаточно прав для совершения операции');
        }
    }
...
```

Как-то так.

Еще можно по-сложному. Например, завести список всех возможных действий (редактирование своего профиля, редактирование чужого профиля, удаление учетной записи, комментирование, ..., N), хранить эти все разрешения и привязывать к учетной записи. А при попытке совершить какое-то действие — проверять, разрешено ли это конкретному пользователю:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];

if ($action == 'save-user-profile')
    {
    if ($_SESSION['user']['access'][$action])
        {
        $db->users->replacerow($_POST['profile']);
        echo 'Профиль успешно сохранен';
        }
    else
        {
        header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 403 Forbidden');
        die('Недостаточно прав для совершения операции');
        }
    }
```

Этот подход сложнее: нужно продумать стратегию хранения этих разрешений, придумать, как исключить коллизии в их наименованиях... Зато вы всегда сможете какому-то конкретному пользователю дать возможность, скажем, удалять профили, при этом не давая возможность редактировать их.

Answer (score 5):

В простейшем случае в базе данных создается таблица возможных ролей, а в таблицу пользователя добавляется ссылка на нее. **При авторизации в сессию пользователя записывается его роль.** После чего при отображении любого раздела или даже элемента на странице можно проверить роль пользователя и разрешить либо запретить ему доступ. Если же пользователь не авторизован, ему можно присвоить роль по-умолчанию, вроде *гостя*. Чуть подробней с более сложным примером данной модели можно почитать здесь: [Управление привилегиями пользователя на основе ролей](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1444). С некоторыми различиями и усложнениями, это самая распространенная схема разграничения прав пользователей на сайтах, насколько я могу судить.

Дополнительно можно почитать про [ACL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACL), которая часто используется совместно с ролями. При этом каждому пользователю назначается список операций, которые он может совершать в отношении того или иного субъекта (например, статьи или записи в блоге). При этом список может назначаться как для каждого отдельного пользователя, так и для группы пользователей (роли).

Это, конечно, не все. Различных систем контроля доступа много. Думаю, полезным будет ознакомиться с тем как это реализовано в других CMS.